# page having query string expires if navigating back to that page in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

i am using query string to get the search parameters entered by user, in codeigniter but if i am going on another page, and then navigating back to that page, then, page expires and i has to be reload that page to get that page with search result.

so, any technique in codeigniter, using which we can get page having search results immediately when navigating back to that page.

```
public function search_freelancer($limit,$offset)
{
    $query="SELECT FM.freelancer_id, FM.first_name, FM.last_name, FD.professional_title, FD.profile_image, FD.freelancer_rate, FD.availability_to_work, FD.country_id, FD.city, FD.user_type, FD.company_name, cm.country_name, FD.overview, GROUP_CONCAT( SM.skill_name SEPARATOR ', ' ) AS skills
        FROM freelancer_master AS FM
        LEFT JOIN freelancer_skill AS FS ON ( FS.freelancer_id = FM.freelancer_id )
        LEFT JOIN freelancer_detail AS FD ON ( FD.freelancer_id = FM.freelancer_id )
        LEFT JOIN skill_master AS SM ON ( FS.skill_id = SM.skill_id )
        LEFT JOIN country_master AS cm ON cm.country_id = FD.country_id
        WHERE FD.professional_title LIKE '%".$this->input->get('search_query',TRUE)."%'
        GROUP BY FM.freelancer_id
        LIMIT ".$limit."
        OFFSET ".$offset;

    $data=$this->db->query($query);
    if($data->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        $results=$data->result();
        return $results;
    }
    else
    {
        $results=NULL;
        return $results; 
    }
}
```

controller :

```
public function search_freelancer($limit,$offset)
{
    $this->output->cache(60);

    $data['freelancers']=$this->search_model->search_freelancer($limit,$offset);
    if($data != NULL) {
        $data['categories']=$this->freelancer_profile_model->get_categories();
        $this->load->view('search',$data);
        $this->load->view('template/footer');
    }
}
```

view :

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/country-suggest.js"></script>
<div class="advance-search-container bg-light-gray">
<div class="login-container">
<div class="container">
<h1>Search</h1>

<hr/>

<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12">
<div class="search-container">
 <div class="search-div">
     <div class="simple-search">
         <form name="simple_searcg" id="simple_searcg" class="simple_searcg" method="post" action="" >
    <div class="text-center col-lg-10 col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-md-10" style="float:left;">
     <div class="input-area">
      <input type="text" name="search" id="search" class="input-box" placeholder="Search" value="<?php echo set_value('search'); ?>" style="height:40px;">
      <span class="text-danger" id="error"></span>
     </div><!--end of input-area-->
    </div><!--end of center-->
                <div class="text-center col-lg-2 col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
     <div class="btn-row">
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info simple_search" value="submit" id="submit" name="submit"/>
     </div><!--nmd of btn-row-->
    </div>          
        </div><!--end of simple-search-->
        <div class="advance-search">
   <div class="text-center col-lg-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-xs-12">
    <div class="input-area">   
     <select name="category_id" id="category" value="<?php echo set_value('category_id'); ?>" style="height:40px" >
      <option value="">Select Category</option>
      <?php if(!empty($categories)) {
       foreach($categories as $row) { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row->category_id; ?>"><?php echo $row->category_name; ?></option>
      <?php } } ?>
     </select>
    </div><!--end of input-area-->
   </div><!--end of center-->
   <div class="text-center col-lg-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-xs-12">
    <div class="input-area">   
     <select name="subcategory_id" id="sub_category" value="<?php echo set_value('subcategory_id'); ?>" style="height:40px" >
      <option value="">Select Subcategory</option>
                 
     </select>
    </div><!--end of input-area-->
   </div><!--end of center-->

   <div class="text-center col-lg-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-xs-12">
    <div class="input-area">   
     <input type="text" name="country_name" id="country_name" value="<?php echo set_value('country_name'); ?>" class="input-box" placeholder="Country Name" autocomplete="off">
     <input type="hidden" name="country_id" id="country_id" value="<?php echo set_value('country_id'); ?>" class="input-box" placeholder="Country Name">
     <div id="display_suggestions"></div>
    </div><!--end of input-area-->
   </div><!--end of center-->
   <div class="text-center col-lg-2">
    <div class="btn-row">
     <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info filter_search" value="submit" id="submit" name="submit"/>
    </div><!--nmd of btn-row-->
   </div>
  </form>
  <span class="text-danger" id="errors"></span>
        </div><!--end of advance-search-->
        
        <div class="recruiter-search-detail">
  <?php if(!empty($freelancers)) {
   foreach($freelancers as $row) { ?>
    <div class="search-box">
     <div class="image-div col-lg-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-xs-12"> <img id="imgProfile" title="Change profile photo" class="profilePic dropzone img-circle" alt="profile image" src="<?php echo base_url().'upload/profileimage/'.$row->profile_image; ?>" /></div><!--end of col-lg-3-->
      <div class="recruiter-profile col-lg-9 col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-xs-12">
       <p class="freelancer-name"><a href="<?php echo base_url().'recruiter/view_freelancer_profile/'.$row->freelancer_id; ?>"><?php echo $row->first_name." ".$row->last_name; ?><span class="usertype"><?php echo " ".$row->user_type; ?><?php if($row->company_name != "") {echo " | ".$row->company_name;} ?></span></a> <span class="rate"><?php echo $row->freelancer_rate.'/hr'; ?></span></p> 
       <p class="professional-title"><?php echo $row->professional_title; ?><span class="availability"><?php echo $row->availability_to_work; ?></span></p>
       <p class="location"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i><?php echo $row->city.", ".$row->country_name; ?></p>
       <p class="overview"><?php echo $row->overview; ?><a href="<?php echo base_url().'recruiter/view_freelancer_profile/'.$row->freelancer_id; ?>" class="more">more...</a></p> 
       <?php $skills=explode(', ',$row->skills); ?>
       <p class="skills">
        <?php for($i=0;$i<count($skills);$i++) { ?>
         <span><?php echo $skills[$i]; ?></span>
        <?php } ?>
       </p>
      </div>
    </div><!--end of search-box-->
  <?php } } else {
  echo 'No Results'; } ?>
        </div><!--end of recruiter-search-detail-->
    </div><!--end fo search-div-->
       
</div><!--end of search-container-->
</div>
</div>
</div><!--en dof login-container-->
</div>
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 // loading all subcategories on change of categories
 $('#category').change(function(){
  var id=$('#category').val();
  $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>freelancer/load_subcategories/"+id,
   dataType: "json",
   success:function(data) {
    $('#sub_category').html("");
    $('#sub_category').html("<option value=''>Select Subcategory</option>");
    for(i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
     $('#sub_category').append("<option value='"+data[i].subcategory_id+"'>"+data[i].subcategory_name+"</option>");
    }
   }
  });
 });
 $('.simple_search').click(function (e) {
  if($('#search').val() == "") {
   e.preventDefault();
   $('#error').html("search query required !");
   $('#error').show().delay(7000).fadeOut();
  }
  else if($('#search').val().length < 3) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $('#error').html("enter 3 or more characters !");
   $('#error').show().delay(7000).fadeOut();
  }
  else {
   //$('#simple_searcg').submit();
   $('#simple_searcg').attr('action', '<?php echo base_url() ?>'+'search/search_freelancer/1/0/?search_query='+$('#search').val()+'&cat='+$('#category').val()+'&subcat='+$('#sub_category').val()+'&cnt='+$('#country_id').val());
   //$(location).attr("href", '<?php echo base_url() ?>'+'search/search_freelancer/1/0/?search_query='+);
  }
 });
 $('.filter_search').click(function (e) {
  if($('#search').val() == "" && $('#category').val() == "" && $('#sub_category').val() == "" && $('#country_name').val() == "") {
   e.preventDefault();
   $('#errors').html("atleast one parameter required !");
   $('#errors').show().delay(7000).fadeOut();
  }
  else {
   $('#simple_searcg').attr('action', '<?php echo base_url() ?>'+'search/search_filter_freelancer/1/0/?search_query='+$('#search').val()+'&cat='+$('#category').val()+'&subcat='+$('#sub_category').val()+'&cnt='+$('#country_id').val());
   //$('#simple_searcg').submit();
  }
 });
});
</script>
```

Comment: please some one help me as soon as possible, it is urgent !

Comment: You can use `session` or `localstorage` to save the query